# SwipeMenuListView does not swipe completely, if it's inside a scroll view

Tags: android, listview, scrollview

https://github.com/baoyongzhang/SwipeMenuListView

SwipeMenuListView works fine on its own. But when I encapsulate it inside a vertical scrollview, the menu items of the list view do not swipe properly and all the menu items are not visible on swipe. What is the issue and how do I fix it?

I need it inside a vertical scroll view, because there are other textviews in the activity. I want to be able to scroll the entire activity together.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the onTouchListener of ScrollView is Overridden by the onTouchListener of Swipe.

Try to use this lib:

> https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidSwipeLayout

Is very simple, download the file: [AndroidSwipeLayout-v1.1.8.jar](https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidSwipeLayout/releases/download/v1.1.8/AndroidSwipeLayout-v1.1.8.jar), paste in your **libs** folder and use like this in your xml item of RecyclerView:

```
<com.daimajia.swipe.SwipeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/bottom_wrapper"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/primary_color"
            android:tag="Bottom1"
            android:weightSum="1">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/delete"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:src="@android:drawable/ic_delete"
                android:tint="@android:color/white" />
        </LinearLayout>


        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/exercise_item"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:text="ExampleText"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="@color/primary_color_dark" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </com.daimajia.swipe.SwipeLayout>
```

You have to use 2 Layouts, the first is the hidden before the swipe.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Another way that I found out that could work, is if I make the textviews a part of the header view for the swipe list views. My solution worked for me.